# Coding HTML e-mail - added image outline/border - gmail and Outlook

Tags: css, gmail, outlook-2007, html-email, outlook-2003

I am coding a simple HTML e-mail and I am experiencing strange behaviour in gmail and Outlook 2003 and 2007. There is a white space below all images. My inline styling for images looks like this:

```
border: none;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
height: auto;
line-height: 100%;
outline: none;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: capitalize;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
```

All styling is taken from MailChimp HTML code and should avoid inconsistencies. Do you have any experiences with this? Images are inside table td markup. Table cells have cellspacing and cellpadding set to 0 as well. Here is a screenshot of the problem: http://cl.ly/EnFt/o

Comment: what's the css on the table cells? this looks like some kind of border on the table td/tr - also, how about using `<td rowspan="2"></td>` for the middle image and not split it in two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images are `inline` by default. That small gap you're seeing is the space for descenders such as those on 'g' and 'q'. To combat the problem, you need to explicitly set all images to be `block` elements, like this:

```
<img src="path/to/img.jpg" style="display:block;" border="0" alt="My Image" />
```

You can use a service like [premailer](http://premailer.dialect.ca/), which lets you add this style in the `head` of your HTML file, and will automatically place it inline for you.

It's worth mentioning that `display:block;` will, obviously, mean that each image should be in a separate `td` or similar: images that need to display side-by-side will be pushed down below each other.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `style="display:block;"` to image tag.Its works fine.

Answer (score 0):

write `border:0;` in your `<img>` tag. Like this:

```
<img  style="vertical-align:top; border:0;">
```